# Is there a way to save image data as a list/array in Python 2.7 or numpy?

Tags: python, image, list, python-2.7, numpy

I want to save image data as a list/array in memory so I can read it somewhere else. The default scripting language is Python 2.7 with numpy added so I have to do can be done with those.

Answer (score 1):

Creates a list of tuples

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('ubuntu.jpg')
imglist = list(img.getdata())

print imglist
```

For `numpy`

```
import numpy

print numpy.array(img.getdata(), numpy.uint8).reshape(img.size[1], img.size[0], 3)
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't have PIL installed on the company systems.

Comment: It's png or bmp, but I can save to other formats if that helps.

Comment: I think that without a library you'd be looking at opening and parsing the image files yourself. Can you run in a virtualenv and install PIL?

Comment: Thanks I don't know virtualenv but basically I am not allowed to use anything other than what the application comes out of the box which is python 2.7 with numpy.

Comment: [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) would be ideal. I don't think its there by default, so it might not be an option. So they will let you install numpy but no other packages? It seems incredibly restrictive. You may have no option but to parse the individual image file formats you want to use. That sounds like a lot of work and I don't know how to do this.

Comment: `scipy` has some [image manipulation functionality](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/image_processing/). That's part of `numpy`. I believe it uses `PIL` under the hood though :(

Comment: No the default dev environment of the app I have to use comes with python 2.7 with numpy added. I can't add anything myself. I thought numpy might have something.

Comment: Sorry I cant help beyond that. Hopefully my answer will be useful to someone else at a later date.